# MySql Server on 2 ethernet adapters

Tags: mysql

I have a server with Mysql  that have 2 ethernet adapters. I can make conections only for LAN1 that has the IP  192.168.2.xxx. For the LAN2 I have IP 192.168.1.xxx and I cannot make the connections. MySql Server has 192.168.2.1 and it listen on 3306.

[image: server with 2 different ethernet adapters]

Comment: Is the server configured to listen on both adapters?

Comment: No, and I don't know where to make the changes to do that. Thanks.